# Wordpress Error blank page In section website

Tags: errors

I installed plugin coming soon seedprod after that i uninstall it i get blank page in my website ,admin section still work good problem just with my theme, i cleared cache,i rename all plugins but still get this error how to i can solve that ?

Debug log

> [27-Mar-2019 19:23:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_mental_seo_description() in /home/hibaiamc/www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mental/header.php on line 21
>   [27-Mar-2019 19:23:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_mental_seo_description() in /home/hibaiamc/www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mental/header.php on line 21
>   [27-Mar-2019 19:24:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_mental_seo_description() in /home/hibaiamc/www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mental/header.php on line 21
>   [27-Mar-2019 19:29:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_mental_option() in /home/hibaiamc/www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mental/single-gallery.php on line 15

Comment: I recommend to restore the theme from the backup that was before installing the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, there is probably not too much we can help with without looking the code and determining why it's there in the first place. My recommendation would be to find this function get_mental_seo_description() and comment it and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Javier! A response like this might be better as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough rep points to comment. T.T